# Find the largest possible number of people in such a tower

Tags: algorithm

First, let's see the question,

A circus is designing a tower routine consisting of people standing atop one another’s
shoulders. For practical and aesthetic reasons, each person must be both shorter and lighter than the person below him or her. Given the heights and weights of each person in the circus, write a method to compute the largest possible number of people
in such a tower.

```
EXAMPLE:
Input:
        (ht, wt): (65, 100) (70, 150) (56, 90) (75, 190) (60, 95) (68, 110)
Output: The longest tower is length 6 and includes from top to bottom: 
        (56, 90) (60,95) (65,100) (68,110) (70,150) (75,190)
```

But I don't quite understand the solution as follows:

Proposed solution by the book:

- Step 1. Sort all items by height
  first, and then by weight. This means
  that if all the heights are unique,
  then the items will be sorted by
  their height. If heights are the
  same, items will be sorted by their
  weight. Example: »»Before sorting:
  (60, 100) (70, 150) (56, 90) (75,
  190) (60, 95) (68,110). »After
  sorting: (56, 90), (60, 95),
  (60,100), (68, 110), (70,150),
  (75,190).
- Step 2. Find the longest sequence
  which contains increasing heights and
  increasing weights. To do this, we:
- a) Start at the beginning of the
  sequence. Currently, max_sequence is 
  empty.
- b) If, for the next item, the
  height and the weight is not greater 
  than those of the previous item, we
  mark this item as “unfit”

  c) If the
  sequence found has more items than
  “max sequence”, it becomes “max
  sequence”.
- d) After that the search    is
  repeated from the “unfit item”,
  until we reach the end of the
  original sequence.

  ```
  public class Question {
  ArrayList<HtWt> items;
  ArrayList<HtWt> lastFoundSeq;
  ArrayList<HtWt> maxSeq;


  / Returns longer sequence
  ArrayList<HtWt> seqWithMaxLength(ArrayList<HtWt> seq1, ArrayList<HtWt> seq2) {
      return seq1.size() > seq2.size() ? seq1 : seq2;
  }


  // Fills next seq w decreased wts&returns index of 1st unfit item.
  int fillNextSeq(int startFrom, ArrayList<HtWt> seq) {
    int firstUnfitItem = startFrom;
    if (startFrom < items.size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
          HtWt item = items.get(i);
          if (i == 0 || items.get(i-1).isBefore(item)) {
              seq.add(item);
          } else {
              firstUnfitItem = i;
          }
        }
    }
    return firstUnfitItem;
  }


  // Find the maximum length sequence
  void findMaxSeq() {
    Collections.sort(items);
    int currentUnfit = 0;
    while (currentUnfit < items.size()) {
        ArrayList<HtWt> nextSeq = new ArrayList<HtWt>();
        int nextUnfit = fillNextSeq(currentUnfit, nextSeq);
        maxSeq = seqWithMaxLength(maxSeq, nextSeq);
        if (nextUnfit == currentUnfit) 
          break;
        else 
          currentUnfit = nextUnfit;
    }
  }
  ```

  }

  Question,

  1> what is the usage of the function fillNextSeq?
  2> why check "items.get(i-1).isBefore(item)" rather than compare the current item with the latest one in the seq?

Assume the sorting list is (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 2), based on the function of fillNextSeq,

first (1, 5) will be pushed into the sequence. Then item (2, 1) will not be pushed into the sequence b/c weight of (2,1) is smaller than (1, 5). Next, since (2, 1) is before (2, 2), so (2, 2) will be pushed into the sequence.

Now, the sequence contains (1, 5) and (2, 2) which is not correct b/c the weight of (1, 5) is larger than that of (2, 2).

Thank you

Comment: This is called the longest increasing subsequence problem. Also note that height and weight are interchangeable (you can sort by weight first).

Comment: If you copy a question from a textbook "Cracking the coding interview", you must at the very least cite it. -1

Answer (score 2):

The usage of fillNextSeq is to fetch the next sequence of increasing height/weight in your group. It does this by adding successive items to the ArrayList seq until it comes across a heavier or taller person.

The function of `items.get(i-1).isBefore(item)` is to check if the next person is shorter and lighter than the current one. Remember that you have already sorted your people by height and weight, so if the next person in sequence is taller or heavier than the current person then they will come before the current person in the sorted array. So the line in question IS comparing the current item with the latest one in the sequence, it's just doing it by comparing their positions in the sorted array.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Hello Raskolnikov, Thank you for your comments. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use dynamic programming resolve this problem. Here is my idea:

```
L(j) -- the largest possible people ending at j ( 0 < j < n)
L(j) = max { L(i) } + 1 where i<j && ht(i)< ht(j) && wt(i)< wt(j)
we're looking for max{L(j)} where 0<j<n.
```

For each j, we hold an array list. The ht and wt of the persons within the array list increases. When dealing with the jth person, we do binary search on the array list of all the

```
List<HtWt> F( HtWt[] in, int n){

   ArrayList<HtWt> out = new ArrayList<HtWt>(n);
   out[0].add(int[0]); 

   int maxl = 0, tj = 0;

   for(int j = 1; j < n; j++){

      // choose the longest among all available
      int jl = 0, ti = 0, tp = 0;

      for( i = 0; i < j; i++){

         // find the first greater element in out[i]
         int x = F(out[i], in[j]);

         // find an appropriate position in i to insert j
         if ( x != -1)  
         {
            // compare with the longest list found so far
            if( (out[i].size + 1) > jl ){
              jl = (out[i].size + 1);
              ti = i;
              tp = x;
          }// if             
      }// for i
     out[j] = out[i];
     out[j].add( tp, o[j]);

     if ( out[j].size > maxl){
       maxl = out[j].size
       tj = j;
     } // if
   } // for j

   return out[tj];
 }  // F

 running time: n + nlogn

 For example, (80, 10), (80, 80), (90, 10), (90, 20), (90, 30)
 j = 0, len = 1, out[0] = (80,10) 
 j = 1, len = 1, out[1] = (80,80)
 j = 2, len = 1 , out[2] = (90, 10)
 j = 3, len = 2, out[3] = (80,10)->(90,20)
 j = 4, len = 1, out[4] = (90, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a solution in c# which has two parts.

Part 1:- create a comparer which sorts on basis of both height and weight (height && weight) in ascending order.

Part 2 :- linear search on the sorted array from the end such that a[i]should be less that a[i-1] in both height and weight.

below is the code. i have some some unit test cases and have checked the code is working fine. but some how i feel there is a bug hidden in this solution. **Request the Experts here to validate the code.**

My Person class which implements IComparer

```
public class Person : IComparer<Person>
{

    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }

    public int Compare(Person p1, Person p2)
    {

        if ((p1.Height > p2.Height) && (p1.Weight > p2.Weight))
            return 1;

        return -1;
    }

}
```

My main method

```
public int NumberOfPeople(Person[] p)
    {

        if (p == null || p.Length == 0)
            return -1;

        Array.Sort(p, new Person());
        int last = p.Length - 1;
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = p.Length - 2; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            if ((p[i].Height < p[last].Height) && p[i].Weight < p[last].Weight)
            {
                last = i;
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. but actually the code is related to this question. If i had to create another thread, then i presume that would be marked as duplicate.